# Verify crontab works on container using slim-buster docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cron

### Problem Description

I am unable to see any output from the cron job when I run `docker-compose logs -f cron` after running docker-compose up.

When I attached to the container using VSCode, I navigated to `var/logs/cron.log` and ran the `cat` command and saw no output. Curiously, when I run `crontab -l` I see `* * * * * /bin/sh get_date.sh` as the output.

### Description of Attempted Solution

Here is how I organized the project (it is over engineered at the moment for reasons of extensibility later)

```
├── config
│   └── crontab
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
└── scripts
    └── get_date.sh
```

Here is the details on the above, the contents are simple. Also, it is my attempt to use a lean `python:3.8-slim-buster` docker image so I can run bash or python scripts (not attempted):

#### crontab

```
* * * * * /bin/sh get_date.sh
```

#### get_date.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Current date and time is " "$(date +%D-%H:%M)"
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  cron:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

#Install cron  
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y cron 

# Copying script file into the container.
COPY scripts/get_date.sh .

# Giving executable permission to the script file.
RUN chmod +x get_date.sh

# Adding crontab to the appropriate location
ADD config/crontab /etc/cron.d/my-cron-file

# Giving executable permission to crontab file
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/my-cron-file

# Running crontab
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/my-cron-file

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Creating entry point for cron 
CMD ["cron", "tail", "-f", "/var/log/cron.log"]
```

### Things Attempted

I am new in trying to get cron working in a container environment. I am not getting any error messages, so not sure how I can debug this issue except describe the behavior.

I have changed the content of crontab from `* * * * * root bash get_date.sh` to the above. I also checked out stackoverflow and found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69949431/django-crontab-not-working-on-docker-python3-9-buster-image) but no clear solution was proposed as far as I could tell.

Thanks kindly in advance.

**References**

- [Stackoverflow discussion on running cron inside of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458287/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)
- [How to run cron inside of containers](https://www.airplane.dev/blog/docker-cron-jobs-how-to-run-cron-inside-containers)

Comment: I ran `service cron status` command in the docker container and got `[ ok ] cron is running`. Thus, cron is running, the crontab + script + logging part is not working as desired is the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several issues that are preventing this from working:

1. Your attempt to run `tail` is a no-op: with your `CMD` as written you're simply running the command `cron tail -f /var/log/cron.log`. In other words, you're running `cron` and providing `tail -f /var/log/cron.log` as arguments. If you want to run `cron` followed by the `tail` command, you would need to write it like this:

   ```
   CMD ["sh", "-c", "cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log"]
   ```
2. While the above will both start cron and run the `tail` command, you still won't see any log output...because Debian `cron` doesn't log to a file; it logs to `syslog`. You won't see any output in `/var/log/cron.log` unless you have a syslog daemon installed, configured, and running.

I would suggest this as an alternative:

1. Fix your syntax in  `config/crontab`; for files installed in `/etc/cron.d`, you need to provide the username:

   ```
   * * * * * root /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/get_date.sh
   ```

   I'm also being explicit about the path here, rather than assuming our cron job and the `COPY` command have the same working directory.

   There's another problem here: this script outputs to *stdout*, but that won't go anywhere useful (cron generally takes output from your cron jobs and then emails it to root). We can explicitly send the output to `syslog` instead:

   ```
   * * * * * root /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/get_date.sh | logger
   ```
2. We don't need to make `get_date.sh` executable, since we're explicitly running it with the `sh` command.
3. We'll use busybox for a syslog daemon that logs to *stdout*.

That all gets us:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Install cron and busybox
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
    cron \
    busybox

# Copying script file into the container.
COPY scripts/get_date.sh /usr/local/bin/get_date.sh

# Adding crontab to the appropriate location
COPY config/crontab /etc/cron.d/get_date

# Creating entry point for cron 
CMD sh -c 'cron && busybox syslogd -n -O-'
```

If we build an image from this, start a container, and leave it running for a while, we see as output:

```
Sep 22 00:17:52 701eb0bd249f syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.30.1
Sep 22 00:18:01 701eb0bd249f authpriv.err CRON[7]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Sep 22 00:18:01 701eb0bd249f authpriv.info CRON[7]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 22 00:18:01 701eb0bd249f cron.info CRON[8]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/get_date.sh | logger)
Sep 22 00:18:01 701eb0bd249f user.notice root: Current date and time is  09/22/22-00:18
Sep 22 00:18:01 701eb0bd249f authpriv.info CRON[7]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Sep 22 00:19:01 701eb0bd249f authpriv.err CRON[12]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Sep 22 00:19:01 701eb0bd249f authpriv.info CRON[12]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 22 00:19:01 701eb0bd249f cron.info CRON[13]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/get_date.sh | logger)
Sep 22 00:19:01 701eb0bd249f user.notice root: Current date and time is  09/22/22-00:19
Sep 22 00:19:01 701eb0bd249f authpriv.info CRON[12]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: You can see the complete set of files [here](https://gist.github.com/larsks/56c3b6b7c94a99da1fe2e06319096864).

Comment: Pardon the delay in my response. I do not have enough reputation to upvote, but I gave this as the official answer. This was very helpful!

Comment: @larsks upvote for time saved!

Answer (score 0):

I have had to recently add cron to a debian11 docker. I am not sure I did it the right way, but my docker file copied all of the crontabs into /etc/cron.d (you will need to specify a user). I then included /etc/init.d/cron start in my start up script. While I am not sure it is the "right" way to do this, it seems to work.

Docker file:

```
RUN apt update && \
apt install ... cron

COPY cronjobs /etc/cron.d
```

Start up file (run.sh):

```
...
postfix start \
 && /etc/init.d/cron start \
 && bash
```